# Apple App Store Advanced Analytics

Tags: ios, app-store, analytics, keyword

I have several applications in App Store and I wish to get further advanced analytics for how they are doing. I'm already listed to some sites that do analytics for **Number of Downloads** and for **Online Ranking** (they check every hour where was each app ranked in each country).
I want to have the following:

1. **Landing** - I want to check how people got to my application's App Store / iTunes
   page; from commercial banners, reviews (I want to see that it came
   from a specific web page), from inner banners I have in my apps
   directing to my other apps, etc...
2. **App Store Search / Keywords** - I want to check which keywords were
   effective and which are redundant.
3. **Keywords General Search** - I want to check which keywords are
   efficient in general for the categories my apps belong to.
4. **Users Analytics** - I want to check how many of my users have both the Free/Lite and Full versions of my apps. Maybe there are more
   analytics I can look for in this area (if anyone has any good idea).

Any help or direction would be very much appreciated.

Answer (score 5, accepted):

Answers numbered according the question

**1:** What you could do is set your Banners/Ads etc. to a 'middleman' URL on your Server which tracks the User Data and then redirects them to the iTunes App Store Page rather than directly going to the App Store Page. That way you can track the URL's from where the User came from etc. Also Banners and Ads should provide their own Tracking Data which could also help? For reviews, you could maybe ask the reviewer to use your Application Website Page with directs to this middleman URL and onto the App Store Link rather than just the direct App Store link.

**2 and 3:** I don't think Apple have any sort of tracking in place to the Developers for this kind of data besides the Sales and Trends data you get in iTunes Connect.

**4:** I've found [Flurry Analytics](http://www.flurry.com/) to be an excellent tool for seeing how Users interact with my applications. You can set events in your Program and track various different events. You can easily track the Free/Paid by setting an event for each and then tracking it.  It also provides a wealth of other data which informs you better of your user base. I definitely recommend checking it out for this kind of thing.

Comment: First, thanks for the most helpful info! Second, this Flurry thing looks amazing! I will certainly take it into consideration for my next update. Third, regarding the first bullet - Landing/Banners/etc... assuming that I don't have my own server, do you have any suggestions on how to deal with it? if you know about any tutorial that explains how to do settings for it (if I understand correctly, I'm supposed to have a link to someplace that all the external banners are set to and direct to App Store from there, right?)

Comment: I'm not too sure on the specifics because i've never had to do it myself but maybe this post can help with some of the code: http://prosper.tracking202.com/forum/13/25/analytics-code-on-the-redirectphp-page#14069