# How to determine the keyword searched that resulted in a download from the App store

Tags: ios, app-store

Does the app store have some sort of API where we can determine the origin of a download based on a keyword?

Example: We get a download, we can see which keyword caused that download to occur.

Thanks

Comment: This question appears to be off-topic because it is about the AppStore which is not directly related to programming

Comment: its about an api which IS programming...

Comment: Covers the same ground as [Apple App Store Advanced Analytics](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/6718416/apple-app-store-advanced-analytics).

Answer (score 1, accepted):

This question has been asked so many times already.

The answer is: You cannot.

Answer (score 0):

Unfortunately, there isn't any official API or section in iTunes Connect or anything that would provide that information. You can [file a bug](https://bugreport.apple.com) asking for it to be added, but I wouldn't hold my breath.